# setting the values of sliding windows of an array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, sliding-window

Suppose I have a 2D array with shape `(3, 3)`, call it `a`, and an array of zeros with shape `(7, 7, 5, 5)`, call it `b`. I want to modify `b` in the following way:

```
for p in range(5):
    for q in range(5):
        b[p:p + 3, q:q + 3, p, q] = a
```

Given:

```
a = np.array([[4, 2, 2],
              [9, 0, 5],
              [9, 9, 4]])
b = np.zeros((7, 7, 5, 5), dtype=int)
```

`b` would end up something like:

```
>>> b[:, :, 0, 0]
array([[4, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [9, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [9, 9, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
>>> b[:, :, 0, 1]
array([[0, 4, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 9, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 9, 9, 4, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: What have you actually tried?

Comment: I can't think of anything to do it with in numpy. np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view just returns the window, so I am not sure how to approach this.

Comment: Show a for-loop that actually works as a reference. Right now, your description is pretty ambiguous.

Comment: How about now ?

Comment: Have you run that code? Add The code to make a sample a and b of ones and zeros like you specified, and run it. I can help you improve the implementation of a well defined problem, but I can't tell you what your code should do.

Comment: My apologies, I should have started by writing the for loop. So this is what I would like to do , but in numpy (or any other python library for crunching big tensors)

Comment: Much better. Thank you for keeping up with this.

Comment: This was a nice question

Comment: Glad you found it interesting. Thank you for going into the details in your solution. In case you are curious, the reason I needed to do such an operation is because I'm building a Convolutional Network from Scratch where I need to do backpropogation for back to back Conv Layers. This operation is part of the calculating the error for this Conv layer.

Comment: I was a little curious. If you rearrange your data to be contiguous in the last two dimensions, your assignment will go a lot faster btw. So shape (5, 5, 7, 7)

Comment: I tried implementing it that way, but I can not see why would it go faster. Is it because the strides in the earlier dimensions are smaller ?

Comment: It's because processors load an entire block into the cache whenever you access memory. If you process the entire block, you win because otherwise you're wasting all the other loaded bytes. The goal is to minimize cache hits, which you do by processing memory as contiguously as you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to think about this to make a sliding window view of `b` (6D), slice out the parts you want (3D or 4D), and assign `a` to them.

However, there is a simpler way to do this altogether. The way a sliding window view works is by creating a dimension that steps along less than the full size of the dimension you are viewing. For example:

```
>>> x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> window = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
                 x, shape=(x.shape[0] - 2, 3),
                    strides=x.strides * 2)
[[1 2 3]
 [2 3 4]]
```

I'm deliberately using [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) rather than [`np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html) here because it has a certain flexibility that you need.

You can have a stride that is *larger* than the axis you are viewing, as long as you are careful. Contiguous arrays are more forgiving in this case, but by no means a requirement. An example of this is [`np.diag`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html). You can implement it something like this:

```
>>> x = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> diag = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
               x, shape=(min(x.shape),),
                  strides=(sum(x.strides),))
array([ 0,  5, 10])
```

The trick is to make a view of only the parts of `b` you care about in a way that makes the assignment easy. Because of broadcasting rules, you will want the last two dimensions of the view to be `a.shape`, and the strides to be `b.strides[:2]`, since that's where you want to place `a`.

The first two dimensions of the view will be responsible for making the copies of `a`. You want 25 copies, so the shape will be `(5, 5)`. The strides are the trickier part. Let's take a look at a 2D case, just because that's easier to visualize, and then attempt to generalize:

```
>>> a0 = np.array([1, 2])
>>> b0 = np.zeros((4, 3), dtype=int)
>>> b0[0:2, 0] = b0[1:3, 1] = b0[2:4, 2] = a0
```

The goal is to make a view that strides along the diagonal of `b0` in the first axis. So:

```
>>> np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
        b0, shape=(b0.shape[0] - a0.shape[0] + 1, a0.shape[0]),
            strides=(sum(b0.strides), b0.strides[0]))[:] = a0
>>> b0
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [2, 1, 0],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 2]])
```

So that's what you do for `b`, but adding up every second dimension:

```
a = np.array([[4, 2, 2],
              [9, 0, 5],
              [9, 9, 4]])
b = np.zeros((7, 7, 5, 5), dtype=int)
vshape = (*np.subtract(b.shape[:a.ndim], a.shape) + 1,
          *a.shape)
vstrides = (*np.add(b.strides[:a.ndim], b.strides[a.ndim:]),
            *b.strides[:a.ndim])
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(b, shape=vshape, strides=vstrides)[:] = a
```

**TL;DR**

```
def emplace_window(a, b):
    vshape = (*np.subtract(b.shape[:a.ndim], a.shape) + 1, *a.shape)
    vstrides = (*np.add(b.strides[:a.ndim], b.strides[a.ndim:]), *b.strides[:a.ndim])
    np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(b, shape=vshape, strides=vstrides)[:] = a
```

I've phrased it this way, because now you can apply it to any number of dimensions. The only expectations is that `2 * a.ndim == b.ndim` and that `b.shape[a.ndim:] == b.shape[:a.ndim] - a.shape + 1`.